# I'm confused about interface abstractions when using IoC

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, ninject

I've recently been trying to learn IoC, and have a couple questions based on the following code:

```
public class WarriorModule : NinjectModule 
{
    public override void Load() 
    {
        Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
        Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble grasping the new concept of interfaces.  Before I would create an interface such as `IRunnable`, implementing the function `void Run()`.  With IoC, I'm now viewing an interface as something that only maps to a single concrete class.  Assuming that, **how would I map multiple concrete classes to an interface?**  I keep reading that you can map multiple interfaces to a single concrete class, but not the other way around (unless this is where contextual mapping comes into play).

Assuming interfaces only map to a single object, **when should I create an interface as opposed to having an object bind to itself?**  Either way you will have to change the same piece of code when a mapping changes correct?

---

Edit: I marked the answer I did because it helped me personally.  Both comments are equally informative though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I recently [addressed this topic from a more general viewpoint](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/02/InterfacesAreNotAbstractions.aspx). The bottom line is that there's a tendency for loosely coupled code to produce an **overabundance of 1:1 interfaces**. This is contrary to the [Reused Abstractions Principle](http://www.codemanship.co.uk/parlezuml/blog/?postid=934).

However, this is more of an **application design issue** than it's an issue regarding particular DI Containers. While I don't know Ninject, all other containers I've ever worked with (Castle Windsor, StructureMap, Spring.NET, Autofac, Unity, and even MEF) can map multiple implementations to the same interface. How they do this differ slightly, but I cover all of them in part IV of [my book](http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=1150_236) - unfortunately, Ninject is not covered in the book.

Comment: This helped me get back on track: "there's a tendency for loosely coupled code to produce an overabundance of 1:1 interfaces".  Thank you for that - I feel like the concepts are finally sinking in after three days -.-

Answer (score 20):

A good IoC container should not change the way interfaces are used:

1. An interface should be designed for the component that is using it as dependency and not the class that is implementing it. (interface segregation principle)
2. A class can implement several interfaces. But this should only be done if those interfaces are for the same kind of service so that the class does exactly one thing. If the interfaces are for two different things they should be implemented by two different classes. (single responsibility principle)
3. Several classes can implement the same interface if you need multiple strategies for this type of service.

Ninject allows using interfaces this way using two different concepts:

1. Conditional bindings: If several classes implement the same interface you have to specify which implementation is used in which case. This is done using conditions:

   `Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>().When(ctx => TodayIsSunday());`

   `Bind<IWeapon>().To<Dagger>().When(ctx => !TodayIsSunday());`
2. Multiple Interfaces: See my blogpost http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/12/08/ninject-extension-contextpreservation-explained/

Comment: +1 While I can't comment on the Ninject specifics, I completely agree on the general points put forward here.