# IoC (Windsor) - What is a "Default Interface"?

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Can someone please explain the difference between

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(BigCompanyRepository))
 .WithService.DefaultInterface()
```

and

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(BigCompanyRepository))
 .WithService.AllInterfaces()
```

What is meant by a "default interface"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a heuristic that [looks for an implementation of an interface by removing the leading `I`](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md):

- IFoo -> Foo
- IBar -> Bar
- IKitchenSink -> KitchenSink

However, in my opinion, using this feature smells of an [over-abundance of 1:1 interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144622/confusion-with-interface-abstraction/5146578#5146578).

Comment: ok, but isn't the whole point of the 1:1 the DI of components/services  that only have one (pluggable) implementation for this application instance (whether it be a test fixture or a web app) - the point being: pluggability?

Comment: Actually it can also match things like: `IFoo`--> `MarksSuperFoo` Basically it looks if, after you remove the leading `I` the class name __contains__ the interface name