# Is Func<in T, out TResult> appropriate to use as a ctor arg when applying Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, delegates, inversion-of-control, func

Example:

```
public class BusinessTransactionFactory<T>  where T : IBusinessTransaction
{
    readonly Func<Type, IBusinessTransaction> _createTransaction;

    public BusinessTransactionFactory(Func<Type, IBusinessTransaction> createTransaction)
    {
        _createTransaction = createTransaction;
    }

    public T Create()
    {
        return (T)_createTransaction(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Container setup code utilising same:

```
public class DependencyRegistration : Registry
{
    public DependencyRegistration()
    {
        Scan(x =>
        {
            x.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
            x.WithDefaultConventions();
            x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(Repository<>));
            x.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRepository<>));
        });

        Scan(x =>
        {
            x.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
            x.AddAllTypesOf<IBusinessTransaction>();
            For(typeof(BusinessTransactionFactory<>)).Use(typeof(BusinessTransactionFactory<>));
            For<Func<Type, IBusinessTransaction>>().Use(type => (IBusinessTransaction)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(type));
        });


        For<ObjectContext>().Use(() => new ManagementEntities());
    }
}
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Mechanics**

On the mechanical level, it's perfectly fine to used delegates, since a delegate is basically an [anonymous Role Interface](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/05/28/DelegatesAreAnonymousInterfaces.aspx). In other words, whether you inject a delegate or interface or abstract base class doesn't really matter.

**Concepts**

On the conceptual level it's important to keep in mind the **purpose of Dependency Injection**. You may be using DI for different reasons than me, but IMO the purpose of DI is to **improve the maintainability** of a code base.

Whether or not this goal is accomplished by injecting delegates instead of interfaces is doubtful.

**Delegates as dependencies**

The first concern is about how well a delegate **communicates intent**. Sometimes an interface name communicates intent in itself, whereas a standard delegate type hardly does.

As an example, the *type* alone doesn't communicate much intent here:

```
public BusinessTransactionFactory(Func<Type, IBusinessTransaction> createTranscation)
```

Luckily, the `createTranscation` name still implies the role played by the delegate, but just consider (for argument's sake) how readable that constructor would have been if the author had been less careful:

```
public BusinessTransactionFactory(Func<Type, IBusinessTransaction> func)
```

In other words, using delegates *shifts the focus from the name of the type to the name of argument*. That's not necessarily a problem - I'm just pointing out that you need to be aware of this shift.

**Discoverability versus Composability**

Another concern is about discoverability versus composability when it comes to the types implementing the dependencies. As an examples, both of these implement public `Func<Type, IBusinessTransaction>`:

```
t => new MyBusinessTransaction()
```

and

```
public class MyBusinessTransactionFactory
{
    public IBusinessTransaction Create(Type t)
    {
        return new MyBusinessTransaction();
    }
}
```

However, in the case of a class, it's almost incidental that the concrete non-virtual `Create` method matches the desired delegate. **It's very composable, but not very discoverable**.

On the other hand, when we use interfaces, classes become part of **is-a** relationships when they implement interfaces, so it generally becomes easier to find all implementers and group and compose them accordingly.

Note that this is not only the case for programmers reading code, but also for DI Containers. Thus, it's easier to implement **Convention over Configuration** when you use interfaces.

**1:1 interfaces versus the RAP**

Some people have noticed that when attempting to use DI they end up with a lot of 1:1 interfaces (e.g. `IFoo` and a corresponding `Foo` class). In these cases, the interface (`IFoo`) seems redundant and it seems tempting to just get rid of the interface and use a delegate instead.

However, [many 1:1 interfaces are really a symptom of a violation of the Reused Abstractions Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144622/confusion-with-interface-abstraction/5146578#5146578). When you refactor a code base to reuse the same abstraction in multiple places, it makes sense to explicitly model the *role* of that abstraction as an interface (or abstract base class).

**Conclusion**

Interfaces are more than mere mechanics. They explicitly model roles in an application code base. Central roles should be represented by interfaces, whereas one-off factories and their ilk can be consumed and implemented as delegates.

Comment: I like using delegates as dependencies. For one thing, it makes unit tests much simpler. An interesting side effect is that you can define APIs in terms of delegates and avoid actually writing any code - just look at the OWIN specification for example. Once you start injecting delegates, code starts to look more functional. I wrote a while back about how a 'currying container' would allow one to write C# code entirely using delegates (http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/03/thought-experiment-curry-facility.html).

Comment: As far as readability goes, you could just as simply define your own delegates rather than using the built in Func and Action. That would also get around the discoverability and duplicate signatures problems.

Comment: How does defining custom delegates help with discoverability? Even with a custom delegate type, I don't see any *easy* way to scan an assembly for matching methods.

Answer (score 5):

I personally don't like to see `Func<T>` arguments as dependencies in my classes, because I think it makes the code less readable, but I know many developers don't agree with me. Some containers, such as Autofac, even allows you to resolve `Func<T>` delegates (by returning a `() => container.Resolve<T>()`).

There are however, two cases where I don't mind to inject `Func<T>` delegates:

1. When the class that takes the `Func<T>` constructor argument is located in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx), because in that case it's part of the container's configuration and I don't consider that part of the design of the application.
2. When that `Func<T>` is injected in a single type in the application. When more services start depending on that same `Func<T>`, it would be better for readability to create a special `I[SomeType]Factory` interface and inject that.

Answer (score 4):

In the past, I have used both the pattern you mention (a delegate) and a single method interface. Currently, I tend to prefer the use of a single method interface.

The code required to mock the dependency is easier to read when using an interface and you will also have the ability to take advantage of automatically typed factories, as @devdigital mentions.

Another thing to consider is that you won't have the overhead of a delegate invocation when using an interface, which could be a valid consideration in very high performance applications.

Answer (score 3):

@Steven's answer is very well thought out; personally I find limited use of `Func<T>` arguments readable.

What I don't understand is the value of `BusinessTransactionFactory<T>` and `IBusinessTransactionFactory<T>`. These are just wrappers around the delegate. Presumably you're injecting `IBusinessTransactionFactory<T>` somewhere else. Why not just inject the delegate there?

I think of `Func<T>` (and `Func<T, TResult>`, etc.) as factories. To me you have a factory class implementing a factory interface wrapping a factory delegate, and that seems redundant.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I deleted the interface already :) Having the BusinessTransactionFactory is imo more readable. This class is used in the UI. I do not want that you have many constructors of funcs instead only one class has the func. I will update my question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the real question here is whether the dependency type should be considered a contract.

In the case of a Func delegate, you are declaring a dependency on a certain method structure, but nothing more. You cannot deduce the range of accepted input values (pre-conditions), constraints on the expected output (post-conditions), or what they mean exactly by looking at this structure. For example, is null an acceptable return value? And if it is, then how should it be interpreted?

In the case of an interface, you have a contract agreed upon by both parties: the consumer explicitly declares that it needs a particular interface, and the implementer explicitly declares to provide it. This goes beyond structure: the documentation of the interface will talk about the pre-conditions, post-conditions and semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is perfectly acceptable, although if you are using a container, more and more of them now support auto typed factories which would be preferable.

- Castle Windsor - [Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)
- Ninject - [Factory Extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory)

Answer (score 0):

IF you inject Func I thin the code will be lazy, so in some case if you class depends from lots of other dependencies maybe is beter to inject Funct in that case. Im I right.

Sorry for my bad english