# Dependency Injection & using interfaces?

Tags: interface, dependency-injection

I've noticed that a lot of developers define an interface for **EVERY** class that is going to be injected using DI framework. What are the advantages of defining Interfaces for every class?

Comment: Your question is valid and interesting question, but it is a bit vague and not very specific (no code examples for instance), which is why people downvoted it and voted it to be closed.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144622/im-confused-about-interface-abstractions-when-using-ioc/5146578#5146578

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Letting your *application components* (the classes that contain the application logic) implement an interface is important, since this promotes the concept of:

> Program to an interface, not an implementation.

This is effectively the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (DIP). Doing so allows you to replace, intercept or decorate dependencies without the need to change consumers of such dependency.

But still, the DIP is not the only principle to consider. In many cases developers will be violating other parts of the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles (DIP is one out of five SOLID principles) when having primarily one-to-one mappings between classes and an interfaces in their applications. One of the principles that is almost certainly violated in that case is the [Open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), because when every class has its own interface, it is not possible to extend (decorate) a set of classes with cross-cutting concerns (without dynamic proxy generation trickery that is).

In the systems I write, I define two generic interfaces that cover the bulk of the code of the business layer. They are called `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` and an `IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>`:

```cs
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}
```

Besides the nice side effect of not having to define many interfaces, this allows great flexibility and ease of testing. You can read more about it [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/commands) and [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/queries).

Depending on the system I write, I might also use interfaces such as:

- `IValidator<T>` for validating messages
- `ISecurityValidator<T>` for applying security restrictions on messages
- `IRepository<T>`, the repository pattern
- `IAuthorizationFilter<T>` for applying authorization/security filtering on `IQueryable<T>` queries.

Depending on the system I write, somewhere between 80% and 98% of all components implement one of these generic interfaces I define. This makes applying most cross-cutting concerns to those so called [joinpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25779864/264697) trivial.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't design to interfaces, you are going to be hamstrung when it comes time to refactor your code and/or add enhancements.  Using a DI framework is not really at issue when it comes to designing to an interface.  What DI gives you is late-binding and much better ability to write unit tests.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20090403080558/http://benpryor.com/blog/2006/08/23/java-advantages-of-interfaces/