# Spring AOP and AspectJ on same method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a question about using aspectJ and spring aop method intercepting. I created 2 annotations: `@AJTest` and `@SAOPTest`.

```
package com.test.company;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class AJTestAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(AJTest)")
    public void aJTest() {
    }

    @Around("aJTest()")
    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            long finish = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            System.out.println("Method execution time: " + (start - finish));
        }
    }
}
```

registered it

```
package com.test.company;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AJConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AJTestAspect ajTestAspect() {
        return new AJTestAspect();
    }
}
```

and other

```
package com.test.company;

import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;

public class SAOPInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Number of parameters " + methodInvocation.getArguments().length);
        return methodInvocation.getMethod().invoke(methodInvocation.getThis(), methodInvocation.getArguments());
    }
}
```

and register it

```
package com.test.company;

import org.springframework.aop.Advisor;
import org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut;
import org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class SpringSAOPTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Advisor springAopTestAdvisor() {
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression("@annotation(com.test.company.SAOPTest)");
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, new SAOPInterceptor());
    }
}
```

and added it to my method in controller

```
package com.test.company;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController
    public class TestController {
    
        @SAOPTest
        @AJTest
        @GetMapping("/test")
        public String doSomething(@RequestParam("firstParam") String firstParam, @RequestParam("secondParam") Integer secondParam) throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(2_500);
            return firstParam + " " + secondParam;
        }
    }
```

Application class

```
package com.test.company;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class AopTestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AopTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

but when i call it by `http://localhost:8080/test?firstParam=test&secondParam=2` i can't see message with time of execution of the method, but can see how many parameters were passed to the method. If I'll remove `@SAOPTest` - method time of execution is worked as expected, but it is not working with both annotations. Is it the problem with proxy object created by spring, or I missed something?

Comment: Could you try with the complete path of the annotation in the pointcut expression . example : `@annotation(xxx.yyy.abc.AJTest)`

Comment: all classes in the same package, but it is not working aswell
`@Pointcut("@annotation(com.test.company.AJTest)")`

Comment: How are you running this? You have multiple configuration? How are those loaded? Is this Spring Boot or plain Spring or ... For `@AspectJ` you also need to `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` on your configuration (if this isn't a Spring Boot app).

Comment: This is spring-boot demo project for the example with 1 endpoint

Comment: Please include the packages in your sources and include your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

Comment: You talk about AspectJ vs. Spring AOP. To me it looks as if you use Spring AOP in both cases, just a full-blown aspect in one case and an advisor in the other case. If you want to convince me that you use native AspectJ, please explain how you weave the aspect: compile-time or load-time weaving? I guess, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub would be the easiest way to make your problem reproducible and help other to analyse the situation instead of relying on textual descriptions only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interceptor does not proceed correctly. Please read the `MethodInterceptor` javadoc. The interceptor should look like this:

```java
public class SAOPInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
  @Override
  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Number of parameters " + methodInvocation.getArguments().length);
    return methodInvocation.proceed();
  }
}
```

Besides, your aspect calculates time wrong, too. First, you say `finish = System.currentTimeMillis() - start` and later you print `start - finish`. Either you should subtract `finish - start` or calculate the time spent in the variable, but not both and not `start - finish`. Why not simply `System.out.println("Method execution time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));`?

Comment: Awesome thanks
proceed() instead of method.invoke() solved the problem.
Yes I know the calculation is wrong, the question was why my annotation for aspectj was supressed by spring aop method interceptor