# Does Dependency Injection go against OOP?

Tags: interface, dependency-injection

I feel like using Dependency Injection is changing the way I write my object oriented code. For instance, below is what I would do without DI

```
Interface: DataAdapter
SqliteDataAdapter implements DataAdapter
XMLDataAdapter    implements DataAdapter
OracleDataAdapter implements DataAdapter

// Initialization
DataAdapter adapter = new SqliteDataAdapter();
DataAdapter adapter = new XMLDataAdapter();
DataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
```

but using DI my code structure would be:

```
Interface: DataAdapter
SqliteDataAdapter implements ISqliteDataAdapter,  DataAdapter
XMLDataAdapter    implements IXMLDataAdapter, DataAdapter
OracleDataAdapter implements IOracleDataAdapter, DataAdapter

// Initialization
ISqliteDataAdapter adapter = new SqliteDataAdapter();
IXMLDataAdapter    adapter = new XMLDataAdapter();
IOracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
```

The reason for this change is that in my module I can **bind 1 interface to 1 class**.
Is this a bad practice? If yes what is the correct solution?

Doesn't DI change the whole purpose of using interfaces?

**EDIT:**
The following is my binding for DI container

```
bind(ISqliteDataAdapter.class).to(SqliteDataAdapter.class);
bind(IXMLDataAdapter.class).to(XMLDataAdapter.class);
bind(IOracleDataAdapter.class).to(OracleDataAdapter.class);
```

If i do as suggested, how would I be able to use multiple adapters? What if I need to use both XMLDataAdapter and SQLDataAdapter in my application?

```
bind(DataAdapter.class).to(SqliteDataAdapter.class);
```

**Edit:**

Here is the current call to get an instance:

```
@inject protected ISqliteDataAdapter dataAdapter;
```

Here is how I should do it with having 1 interface only:

```
@inject protected DataAdapter dataAdapter;
// In this case I don't have a choice on which type of data adapter It's going to create
// It's already defined in my module file and it's pointing to one of the 3 DataAdapters
```

So what I'm trying to understand is, how can I structure my code in a way that I have control over the type of object it's injecting, without having interface for every type of DataAdapter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'm confused about interface abstractions when using IoC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144622/im-confused-about-interface-abstractions-when-using-ioc)

Comment: I have read that thread already, and it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Why not? It pretty clearly states that 1:1 interfaces aren't the best direction in which to head. So, no: DI doesn't change the whole purpose of using interfaces. Why would you even want to structure your code as in your second example? Why can't you declare each `adapter` variable as `DataAdapter`? What additional value do the three new interfaces add?

Comment: @RubenBartelink "I'm not talking to you"? In case you haven't noticed, some people go to work during the day. Did you even bother looking at the date this question was posted before responding with your non-sense comment?

Comment: please post the call to the DI container to get an instance based on the interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that DI is a natural consequence of having interfaces. The reason we have interfaces is so that we can write code that doesn't depend on particular class, but instead an work with a multitude of classes without any changes. Even if we expect there to only be one class which does we need, this may change in the future. By programming to interface, we can even account for changes we can't imagine.

DI just uses the above notions in a peculiar way, to maximize the testability and adaptability of code. So I would say the DI is a *really* good practice.

That said, I think there is one warning to be issued for anyone involved with these kinds of systems. There's the danger that we write full-fledged classes like your `SqliteDataAdaptor`, and then push a "extract the interface" button to give the `ISqliteDataAdaptor` interface. This practice is *very* bad, particularly if it happens a lot. Instead, `ISqliteDataAdaptor` should usually be designed first, and then a sensible implementation can be written.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection is about controlling what is instantiated and placing that logic in a single place. The code you write should not change the base types(interfaces) that you use.

In both cases you should have DataAdapter as the type of object you use. It's **you** who decides what the type of the instance that you get from the dependency injection container **not** the container.

also see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: But like I mentioned you can bind an interface to 1 class, so what would be the solution in this case?

Comment: but why can't you use the DataAdapter type in the case where you get the instance from the dependency injection container?

Comment: @LiviuT. It seems like in his system, all components are designed to be potentially injectable. So the question seems to stem more from a strict adherence to "programming to interface" then to DI in particular.

Comment: Ken you are correct. I inject everything and that's why I am forced to create interface for all my classes

Comment: so in his di environment DataAdapter is a base interface but you need specific functionality in ISqliteDataAdapter?

Comment: Please see my updated question, I explained the binding problem I am facing